# Function to Get Value from Registry - 2 issues: DWORD, console error

Tags: powershell, registry

This is ma very simple PowerShell function to get reg value from registry:

```sh
Function GetRegKey {
    Param([String]$GetRegKeyPath, $GetRegKeyName)
    If (Test-Path -Path $GetRegKeyPath) {
        If (Get-ItemProperty -Path $GetRegKeyPath -Name $GetRegKeyName) {
            $GetRegKeyVal = (Get-ItemPropertyValue $GetRegKeyPath $GetRegKeyName)
            Return $GetRegKeyVal
        } Else {
            write-output ("Warning! Path:  '$GetRegKeyPath'  is exist, but RegKey:  '$GetRegKeyName'  is:  not exist.") }           
    } Else {
        write-output ("Warning! Path:  '$GetRegKeyPath'  is not exist!")
        Return $null }
}
```

Example:
`GetRegKey "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "ProgramFilesDir"`
will give output like:
`C:\Program Files`

I have two things what is not working:

1. If $GetRegKeyName is not exist script besides go to command write-output ("Warning! Path:  '$GetRegKeyPath'  is exist, but RegKey:  '$GetRegKeyName'  is:  not exist.") is also display in console error:

[image]

Is this can be somehow avoid? I did try with pipe | Out-Null but its bassically not a solution I guess.

2. Second thing what is not works here is reg with DWORD value.
   Is command Get-ItemProperty -Path $GetRegKeyPath -Name $GetRegKeyName
   can't be used with DWORD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest streamlining your function as follows, which only requires a single [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) (note that I've renamed the function to `GetRegValue`, because it is a registry *value's* (data) that is returned):

```
Function GetRegValue {
  Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String] $KeyPath, 
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String] $ValueName
  )

  try {
    Get-ItemPropertyValue -ErrorAction Stop $KeyPath $ValueName
  }
  catch [System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException] {
    Write-Warning "Path:  '$KeyPath'  does not exist."
  }
  catch [System.Management.Automation.PSArgumentException] {
    Write-Warning "Path:  '$KeyPath' exists, but RegKey:  '$ValueName'  doesn't." 
  }

}
```

- A [`try` / `catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally) statement is used to match errors by their exception type, from which the specific error condition can be inferred.

  - Note that any exception type not matched would result in a script-terminating error; that is, error conditions other than the matched ones cause a fatal error (by default), such as a lack of permissions.
- The [common `-ErrorAction` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters#-erroraction) is used with `Stop` in order to promote *non-terminating* errors to (script-)terminating ones, which allows them to be caught with `try` / `catch`.

  - As an aside: Due to a longstanding bug still present as of PowerShell 7.3.1, `Get-ItemPropertyValue` inappropriately reports a (statement-)terminating error when the key path exists, but not the value name - see [GitHub issue #5906](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5906).
- [`Write-Warning`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-warning) is used to emit the warnings, which uses the dedicated warning [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), which is conceptually preferable and also gives you automatic coloring of the message.

---

As for `DWORD` values:

PowerShell is capable of returning types of all data stored in the registry (they get mapped onto equivalent .NET types), so there shouldn't be a problem with `REG_DWORD` registry values.

You can verify by calling the function above as follows:

```
GetRegValue  HKCU:\Console FontSize
```

This should output an `[int]` (`System.Int32`) value such as `1048576`.

Note that if the value is too large to fit into `[int]`, you'll get a `[uint32]` (`System.UInt32`) value instead.

Comment: I just noticed that `Get-ItemPropertyValue` doesn't honor `-EA Ignore` and `-EA SilentlyContinue` if the error is caused by a missing registry value. `Get-ItemPropertyValue hklm:\software -Name bar -EA Ignore` unexpectedly outputs an error message and adds to `$error`! So `try/catch` actually seems the only way to silence errors due to missing values. Tested with both PS 5.1 and PS 7.3.1.

Comment: Good point, @zett42: `Get-ItemPropertyValue` is ill-behaved - see [GitHub issue #5906](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5906).

Comment: 4 years old bug :(

Comment: @zett42, there's plenty more where that came from, unfortunately.

Comment: I like that solution very much. Thanks one more time @mklement0

Comment: Regarding how to get some detailed info about errors in PS based on your reply I found this article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/catch-powershell-errors-related-to-reading-the-registry/ 
So I implemented one more catch in this fuction:

Comment: Regarding how to get some detailed info about errors in PS based on your reply I found this article: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/catch-powershell-errors-related-to-reading-the-registry/ 
So I implemented one more catch (for no permissions) in this function:
catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException].

 I'm thinking also about all other errors what can be shown. Is there can be command like this:
catch [*] {
    Write-Warning "Other unknown error"
  }

Comment: @MikeZetPL, yes, an unqualified `catch` block (`catch { ... }`), placed last, would act as a catch-all for all errors (exceptions) not matched by their type.

Comment: Perfect. Works really great :) Thanks one more.